# Change color of an element based on it's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I use WordPress to create my web page and I used a plugin called Weekly Class Schedule. It creates a timetable, technically it's made as a table. The limitation of this plugin is that it can have only one color of the table cell when there is and entry.

Now, using JavaScript, how can I change the color of the background, when I know that for example the content of the `td` element is a constant text?

An example of one TD element's class name is `wcs3-cell wcs3-hour-row-10-00 wcs3-day-col-1 wcs3-abs-col-0` but clearly it is dynamically created so I can't really rely on exact names.

I assume that `wcs3-cell` would be the basic class name but below code doesn't work:

```
function f_color() {
    if (document.getElementByClassName('wcs3-cell').value = 'boks') {
        document.getElementByClassName('wcs3-cell').style.background-color = "yellow";
    }
}

f_color();
```

Could you please advise how to fix this? Also, should I use `yellow !important` as a new CSS value to make sure that new code will be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

- you should use `==` when comparing values.
- `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` - note 'Element**s**'
- `td` elements do not have a `value` property - you need to read the `textContent`.
- `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements, so you need to loop over each one and check their values individually.
- When using the CSS style name as a property of the `style` object, you should use the JS notation, in this case `backgroundColor`.

With all that said, try this:

```
function f_color() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('wcs3-cell');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].textContent == 'boks') {
            elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        } 
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/35taad9L/3/)

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's an implementation for that:

```
function f_color() {
    var $elements = $('.wcs3-cell').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == 'boks';
    }).css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
}
```

Comment: Rory, unfortunatelly it didn't help.
I'm not sure though if I correctly assumed the name of the class to use. Do you agree with my assumption?

Comment: Can you please give more information - why did it not help? Was there any errors in the console? As you can see from the fiddle example, it should work fine.

Comment: If the elements have the classes as you specified in the question it should work fine. Here's an updated example http://jsfiddle.net/35taad9L/1/

Comment: Rory, it's possible that I don't know how to use your fiddle page but it doesn't work for me.
It's not being displayed as table and no styling is applied.
When I add CSS code to your fiddle 
.wcs3-cell
{
        background-color: red;
}
it gets a background color but no other styling though.

Comment: I updated my answer for you - try that latest version,

Comment: Ok now your example works (although it's not displayed as a table).
Anyway, do you think that Jai's suggestion from below, that I should put this code after the code that creates this table, is correct?
If so, then I might have a problem finding a correct PHP file for this inside the plugin files.

Comment: Yes, the table has to exist in the DOM *before* you can do anything with it.

Comment: I placed the code in the footer, so it should be loaded at the end and it still doesn't work..

Comment: Not necessarily. If your table is loaded via AJAX you need to place the code in the callback to execute after the request has completed.

Comment: Maybe a different approach.
While looking for a place to paste this code I found a code that actually assigns default color when cell is not empty.
How about changing this part of the code to assign desired color when text is found?
 wcs3_apply_parent_color: function() {
  jQuery('td.wcs3-cell').each(function() {
   var childs = jQuery('.wcs3-class-container', this),
    child_color;
   
   if (childs.length > 0) {
    // Got a child class, let's match color.
    child_color = jQuery(childs).css('background-color');
    jQuery(this).css('background-color', child_color);
    
   }
  });
 },

Comment: Sorry that the code got shattered, I just started posting at this forum and don't really know how to format posts yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` instead of `=` in your if condition statement

Other Mistake you done is inside if statement it is `backgroundColor` not `background-color`.  Please correct it and check

```
 if (document.getElementByClassName('wcs3-cell').value == 'boks') {

  document.getElementByClassName('wcs3-cell').style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

 }
```

Comment: Note that there are a lot more issues than just the operator used.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use *Equality Operator* `==` or `===` to compare values in `if` statement
2. Use `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`

See the highlighted code below:

```js
function f_color() {
  var allElements = document.getElementByClassName('wcs3-cell'),
    totalElements = allElements.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < totalElements; i++) {
    document.getElementByClassName('wcs3-cell').style.backgroundColor = allElements[i].value == 'boks' ? 'yellow' : '';
  }
}

f_color();
```

Comment: Note that there are a lot more issues than just the operator used, and your snippet doesn't appear to do anything useful. In fact it causes an error.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for pointing out mistakes. I've updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

*I used a plugin called Weekly Class Schedule.*

So it seems that you have a dynamically generated `tds` in your page, so now you have to use this function when your table generates the trs/tds completely.

You need to use this:

```
function f_color() {
   var els = document.getElementsByClassName('wcs3-cell'); // get all the tds
   for(var i = 0; i <= els.length-1; i++) { // loop over the length of it
      if (els[i].textContent.trim() === 'boks') { // check the tds text while trimming it.
          els[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; // here change the background color.
       } 
   }
}
```

now call this function when your table row appended in the DOM because if you use it before row generation it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, Jai.
Do you think that placing this code in the footer is a good idea?
Will it be run after the table is created?

Comment: @DonAndress Frankly speaking i don't think so because it depends on the code which generates the `trs/tds`. Better option is to call this function where you are appending the generated `trs/tds` something like `.append()` of jquery or `.appendChild` of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f_color(){

  $('td').each(function(){
  
  
  var text = $(this).text();
    
    if(text == 'Book')
      {
        $(this).css('background','red')
      }
  
  })


}

f_color()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Book</td>

  
</tr>
  <tr><td>Note </td></tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like a few others have pointed out, you are using = rather than == or === . == and === are comparison operators, so you use them to compare two values, whereas = by itself just says that something is something else.

eg

```
var x = y
```

would mean that now the variable x is now whatever y is.

whereas

```
var x === y
```

is asking whether x is identical to y (in both value and type).

```
var x == y
```

is similar but is only asking for value irrespective of type

I made this mistake loads in my code when i first started, be good to get this clear in your head now.

Some more details about this here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp